# Is there any device that enhances the USB signal?

Tags: power-supply, usb, wireless-networking

I want to make a USB cable of 20 meters and that this is able to deliver 500 mA and keep the voltage at about 5V stable.

I have been testing several solutions, such as connecting a self-powered USB hub on the end of the cable.

I would like to know if there is any device—PIC or something similar—that can perform the same function of a hub, but that is more economical.

A diagram for the cable could be:

> USB Connection on a PC <-----------> Repeater <-----------> Cable End

What could I use to achieve this?

Comment: https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=6042 plus a hub at the far end so you can have 5V power.

Comment: "more economical" <-- you can have well-tested, properly enclosed hubs for like 7€, delivered to you the next day or bought at the department store around the corner. I doubt there's anything more economical. But, yes, there used to be "single port" hubs that were sold as repeaters back in the earlier days of USB. They are still available. Also, this is a product recommendation question and hence off-topic.

Comment: To add to Marcus Muller's comment, if you are building custom hardware, a full speed hub IC is about $1-2 USD in small quantities. That is about as cheap as a PIC and a whole lot less work.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Actually what I need is something that reconstructs the signal and that has only one usb port. I'm not interested in a finished product, for example I think a PIC would be great for me. I've been looking for tranceivers and phy, but I can not quite understand the difference between them.

Comment: You've got enough comments that address all what you've just repeated. What you need is de facto a hub, not a PIC or something. One can buy hub ICs.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Can you suggest one that is compatible with the standard n of the wifi (150 mbps)?

Comment: @MarcusMüller In the country where I live there is no such thing as I click on add to the cart I enter my credit card and after 3 days they take me to my house. When someone buys me something from outside, I have to pay 3 or 4 times the value of what they request.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Because I want to connect the usb wifi module (http://www.tp-link.com/ar/products/details/cat-11_TL-WN7200ND.html) on the outside of my house to receive the signal with better quality.

Comment: http://www.ti.com/product/TUSB211 if you're not interested in a finished product.

Comment: Yeah, no. If you need to do that, then you really need is a wifi router that does client mode, and an Ethernet cable back to your computer.

Comment: Get a RJ45, network version that accepts PoE (power over ethernet).

Answer (score 0):

USB max length is 5m so your best bet would be a USB to Cat5 extender, which is usually up to the range of 150ft (45m) with a cost in the 10-30 dollar range, then putting a USB power injector/enhancer cable at the end to meet power requirements, which is in the 2-8 dollar range. This is how some security cameras are installed.

Cat5 handles 360mA max per conductor, not including the loss caused by 2.5ohms per 100ft. Depending on implementation the extender might be able to use multiple conductors but it's less of a gamble to just use the injector/enhancer at the end as the voltage is going to sag regardless at these lengths.

... so you'd have something like this:

Start->USB->Cat5->USB->Power Injector->End

You have not specified the speeds required, which is notable as Cat5 adapters often limit the USB speeds to 1.0.

Comment: I use cat 5e network cable to do the extension. The signal arrives very deteriorated in spite of the fact that I use it in a mobile phone charger. That's why I'm trying to find a solution that corrects the signal.

Answer (score 0):

So this is for a usb wifi access point.

20 meters is super easy, networking can do up to 100m and you can have gigabit.

Instead of some non-standard setup here is an industry standard.  Run a RJ45 outside and plug this into it.  Either get a hub with PoE or a simple PoE injector for approx $10.

[https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0DF-0100-00025&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-*-pla-*-Memory+%28Flash+Memory%29-_-0DF-0100-00025&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIvrjk3YvJ2AIVRB2BCh0OzQJNEAkYBCABEgLZA_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0DF-0100-00025&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Memory+%28Flash+Memory%29-_-0DF-0100-00025&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIvrjk3YvJ2AIVRB2BCh0OzQJNEAkYBCABEgLZA_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Wireless-Access-Point-Router-Network-POE-CPE-Outdoor-High-Power-AP-WiFi-Bridge-/372106411510?_trksid=p2385738.m4383.l4275.c10

There are literally dozens of options on google shopping for wifi ap powered by PoE.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/4-Port-Passive-Gigabit-POE-Injector-Panel-12-48V-POE4PG-for-Ubiquiti-Mikrotik-/202065685457?_trksid=p2385738.m4383.l4275.c10